# Harbor on Kubernetes: Hostname to be used in harbor.cfg

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

am trying to deploy harbor registry in kubernetes cluster.

We need to update the hostname in harbor.cfg to be able to access harbor ui from outside k8s cluster. As per instructions, hostname should be updated with the worker node hostname or IP address.

i have a k8s cluster with 5 workers. what hostname should be defined in harbor.cfg. please advise

Comment: did you tried its service name?

Comment: am yet to generate k8s configuration files using k8s-prepare script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing in kubernetes, you can use the helm charts: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm

Even if you don't have tiller (helm's server) in your cluster, you can generate easily the yaml files with `helm template` or use them as a guide :)